# ORMLite: Updating a foreign object field

Tags: java, android, ormlite

For my current project I decided to use ORMLite (4.46). Currently, I'm experiencing some issues when saving data of a foreign object. Below, a example of my code. The field called "field" is not saved properly (The old data is displayed). Anybody an idea, what's wrong with this code?

Thank you!

Regards
Andreas

Some class:

```
DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = OpenHelperManager.getHelper(context, DatabaseHelper.class)
branch.field = 123423;
Log.d("...", "field:" + branch.field); <-- new value of field is displayed
databaseHelper.getBranchDao().update(branch);
```

Other class:

```
DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = OpenHelperManager.getHelper(context, DatabaseHelper.class);
databaseHelper.getFloorDao().refresh(floor);
databaseHelper.getBranchDao().refresh(floor.branch);
Log.d("...", "branch field:" + floor.branch.field); <-- old value of field is displayed
```

DatabaseHelper:

```
...

public class DatabaseHelper extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper {

    // name of the database file for your application -- change to something appropriate for your app
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "xy.db";
    // any time you make changes to your database objects, you may have to increase the database version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // the DAO objects we use to access the tables
    private Dao<Branch, Integer> branchDao = null;
    private Dao<Floor, Integer> floorDao = null;

    private Context appContext;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION, R.raw.ormlite_config);

        appContext = context;
    }

    /**
     * This is called when the database is first created. Usually you should call createTable statements here to create
     * the tables that will store your data.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db, ConnectionSource connectionSource) {
        try {
            Log.i(DatabaseHelper.class.getName(), "onCreate");
            // Create tables for each domain object here!
            TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, Branch.class);
            TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, Floor.class);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.e(DatabaseHelper.class.getName(), "Can't create database", e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This is called when your application is upgraded and it has a higher version number. This allows you to adjust
     * the various data to match the new version number.
     */
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, ConnectionSource connectionSource, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        try {
            Log.i(DatabaseHelper.class.getName(), "onUpgrade");
            // Drop all tables of domain objects here!
            TableUtils.dropTable(connectionSource, Branch.class, true);
            TableUtils.dropTable(connectionSource, Floor.class, true);
            // after we drop the old databases, we create the new ones
            onCreate(db, connectionSource);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.e(DatabaseHelper.class.getName(), "Can't drop databases", e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Delete and re-create database when user is changed
     */
    public void reCreateDB(){
        //delete the database (onCreate() will be called if database is needed again)
        appContext.deleteDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the Database Access Object (DAO) for our domain class. It will create it or just give the cached
     * value.
     */


    public Dao<Branch, Integer> getBranchDao() throws SQLException {
        if (branchDao == null) {
            branchDao = getDao(Branch.class);
        }
        return branchDao;
    }

    public Dao<Floor, Integer> getFloorDao() throws SQLException {
        if (floorDao == null) {
            floorDao = getDao(Floor.class);
        }
        return floorDao;
    }



    /**
     * Close the database connections and clear any cached DAOs.
     */
    @Override
    public void close() {
        super.close();
    }
}
```

Floor:

```
...

public class Floor {
    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    public int id;

    @DatabaseField(foreign = true, canBeNull = true, foreignAutoRefresh = true, maxForeignAutoRefreshLevel=5)
    public Branch branch;

    public Floor(){}
}
```

Branch:

```
....

public class Branch {

    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    public int id;
    @DatabaseField(canBeNull = true)
    public int field;

    @ForeignCollectionField(eager = true, maxEagerLevel = 99)
    private ForeignCollection<Floor> floors;

    public Branch(){}

    public ForeignCollection<Floor> getEmptyFloorCollection() {
        try {
            return MainActivity.getDatabaseHelper().getBranchDao().getEmptyForeignCollection("floors");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.e("DatabaseHelper", "SQL Exception: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }

    public ForeignCollection<Floor> getFloors() {
        if(floors == null) floors = getEmptyFloorCollection();
        return floors;
    }

    public void setFloors(ForeignCollection<Floor> floors) {
        this.floors = floors;
    }
}
```

Comment: You sure you are dealing with the same `branch` instance?  The code looks good to me.  Another thing to do is to turn on logging to see if there is a problem: http://ormlite.com/docs/android-logging

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Yes it is the same `branch` instance. Could it be an issue that I'm saving `branch.field` in an AsyncTask (doInBackground()). I'm reading `branch.field` after the AsyncTask is finished, but perhaps there are issues when saving data in AsynTasks with ORMLite?

Comment: I don't think the `AsyncTask` has anything to do with it.  If the operation has completed, the Sqlite database should have been updated.  Any chance you are using an object cache?